# Can I have a marginpar with line breaks inside a frame?

Tags: marginpar

I have a command (complements of a contributor here) that puts text in the margin. I would like to frame that text to make it stands out, but when I try to do it I lose the ability to break the text with line breaks. I've tried \frame, \framebox, and \fbox, with the same result. Here is the MWE using \framebox:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\newcommand{\MargNote}[2] % Places text in the margin
    { % start of MargNote
    \marginpar{  % start of  marginpar
        \framebox{ % start of framebox
        \vspace{#1} 
        \footnotesize \textit{\textbf{#2}}  
        }  % end of marginpar
        } % end of framebox
    } % end of MargNote

\begin{document}

\MargNote{0pt}{This is a very \\ long margin note \\ that I would \\ like to break in \\several places.}

\end{document}
```

If I get rid of \framebox the text breaks where indicated and everything is fine, just no frame. It may be that what I want is not do-able, but thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [\framebox](https://latexref.xyz/_005cfbox-_0026-_005cframebox.html) or simply [\fbox`](https://latexref.xyz/_005cfbox-_0026-_005cframebox.html) on top of a [\parbox](https://latexref.xyz/_005cparbox.html); the latter creates a paragraph box and split its content over multiple lines.

[image]

EDIT. I am not convinced you should use `\vspace`. I think `\fboxsep` is better because it controls padding around boxes. This is a length name so you should use `\setlength` to change it, e.g.

```
\setlength\fboxsep{6pt}
```

You might still use `\vspace` but probably outside the `\fbox`.

---

A code for the example:

```latex
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{ragged2e,microtype}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newcommand{\MargNote}[2] % Places text in the margin
{% start of MargNote
  \setlength\fboxsep{#1}
    % \vspace{#1}\footnotesize%
    \marginpar{% start of  marginpar
      \fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\marginparwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{% start of framebox
        \RaggedRight\footnotesize
        \textit{\textbf{#2}}
      }  % end of marginpar
    } % end of framebox
  } % end of MargNote
}


\begin{document}
\MargNote{3pt}{This is a very \\ long margin note \\ that I would \\ like to break in \\several places.}

\kant[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `\dimexpr\marginparwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule`?  `\marginparsep` is probably larger than needed.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, I should have adjusted the `\parbox` for both padding and frame. Thanks.